# Can anyone help me describe the physics of my problem mathematically?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system, advice, gradient-descent

I was unsure if I should post this here or on the Physics page, so I decided to do both. Here's the problem I want to describe: Suppose I have a sphere, discretely represented by a large set of simple planar polygons in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The polygons cover the surface of the sphere and are adjacent to each other with no (or very slight) overlaps between neighbouring polygons. However, the normals of the polygons are the analytical normal of the sphere at the centroid of each polygon, with a perturbation ($<20^{\circ}$) added.

In my actual application (surface tension modelling), the surface can be an arbitrary, smooth, and closed surface. Therefore, unlike for a sphere, I do not know the local surface normal $\textit{a priori}$. I only have the polygonal representation. In order to reduce the perturbations and achieve a smoother distribution of the polygon normals, I want represent the problem as a set of massless plates allowed to freely pivot about their area centroid, with tensile springs connecting each plate with each of its immediate neighbours. The springs are attached at the edges of each plate.

Can anyone help me describe this problem mathematically, in terms of an objective function that I can numerically minimise? It's important to note that I don't actually want to simulate the physics of the plate-spring system. I just want to find its lowest energy state, just so I can compute the polygon normals.

$\textit{p.s.}$ I have tried other discrete methods. But there are still large errors in comparison to the analytical normals. My thinking is that the solution to the plate-spring system will yield the most accurate normals I can hope to achieve.

Comment: See my answer in physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509623/… There I used FEM to calculate the surface. Unfortunately, in a physical forum it is impossible to discuss real physical problems. On the other hand, mathematicians may not be opposed to discuss physical models.